# SQLiteDataReader GetFieldType() returns Int64, but then fails on GetInt64() - is this a bug or feature?

Tags: database, sqlite

When reading from an SQLiteDataReader I'm experiencing some odd behaviour whereby GetFieldType(0) returns typeof(Int64), GetValue(0) returns an Int64, but GetInt64(0) fails with an System.InvalidCastException exception.

It has taken me a rather long time to reproduce this behaviour:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SQLiteType
    {
        [Test]
        public void A()
        {
            var sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;");
            sqlConnection.Open();

            var create = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            create.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE FOO (x INTEGER)";
            create.ExecuteNonQuery();

            var insert = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO FOO VALUES (?)";
            var param = insert.CreateParameter();
            param.Value = new TimeSpan(0); // NOTE INSERTING TIMESPAN DIRECTLY instead of .Ticks
            insert.Parameters.Add(param);
            insert.ExecuteNonQuery();

            var select = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            select.CommandText = "SELECT x FROM FOO";

            var dr = select.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var valueObject = dr.GetValue(0);
                Assert.AreEqual(typeof (Int64), valueObject.GetType());
                var valueType = dr.GetFieldType(0);
                Assert.AreEqual(typeof (Int64), valueType);
                var value = dr.GetInt64(0); // throws System.InvalidCastException 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to occur when the row is created by inserting a TimeSpan value directly into an INTEGER column (instead of e.g. TimeSpan.Ticks which might be more meaningful). Despite this, the datareader is still telling me that column is an Int64.

I'm not exactly sure what the contract is for SQLiteDataReader but I had previously assumed that if GetFieldType() returns a typeof(Int64), then GetInt64() should not fail. Perhaps this is not the case? (It seems quite odd that GetValue() still returns an Int64) Maybe it is an artifact of SQLite's unique dynamic typing system.

Certainly it is not hard to avoid, but for pedagogical reasons I am just curious why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

The root cause may have to do with how types are handled with SQLite:

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity

Even then, this looks like a bug to me; if:

```
dr.GetValue(0).GetType() == typeof(System.Int64)
```

then it should certainly follow that `dr.GetInt64(0)` doesn't throw an exception. I would send an email to sqlite-users@sqlite.org as described here: http://www.sqlite.org/src/wiki?name=Bug+Reports

Please note though that if you replace:

```
param.Value = new TimeSpan(0);
```

with

```
param.Value = new TimeSpan(0).Ticks;
```

then

```
var value = dr.GetInt64(0);
```

works fine. I'm bringing this up because I'm not sure there is any conversion assumption to make when you assign that TimeSpan. For instance, there is no implicit or explicit conversion from `TimeSpan` to `long`.

Comment: Yep - TimeSpan(0).Ticks is what I would do personally, the code I provided is simply something that finally reproduces the error I was encountering. It is interesting to note that even if you insert a TimeSpan(1234), dr.GetValue() still returns a 0l.